# MySQL server has gone away Cloud SQL in App engine with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I´m trying to connect Cloud SQL with App engine this way

```
<?php
 class ConectorBD{
   private $host = 'localhost';
   private $user = 'first_user';
   private $password = '12345';
   private $port = null;
   private $socket = '/cloudsql/instance-name';
   private $connect;

   function initConnect($name_db){
     $this->connect = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $name_db, $this->port, $this->socket);
      if ($this->connect ->connect_error) {
       return "Error:" . $this->conexion->connect_error;
     }else {
       return "OK";
     }
   }
  }
 $con = new ConectorBD();
 echo $con->initConnect('my_db');
?>
```

But the next error appear Error:MySQL server has gone away

Comment: @GAEfan you know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the connection name open Cloud Shell and run command below

> gcloud sql instances describe instance-name

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project_id:sql_instance_region:intance_id;dbname=db_name", "root", "your_root_password");

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(null, "root" , "your_root_password", 'db_name', null, '/cloudsql/project_id:sql_instance_region:intance_id');
```